# Using castle project on VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, castle-activerecord

I've read alot about the Castle Project and decided to start using it, primarilly ActiveRecord. But how to get started?

There's an msi that installs an old release on VS 2005. Nothing happens on my VS 2008.

There's also a bunch of project specific zips available for downloading indivudually. They contain files: dlls and xmls mostly. Like Castle.ActiveRecord.dll. People brighter than me may know where to put these but I have no idea.

I'm using VS 2008 with asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the msi installer. It's been unmaintained for a long time.

How to use Castle.ActiveRecord.dll? Just like any other 3rd party library: put it the "lib" directory of your project (or whatever you want to call it) along with its dependencies (all the DLLs it includes), then click Add Reference in your project and add these DLLs as references.

Then start writing your code. Take a look at the [tutorial](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/creatingdb.html).

If you want Visual Studio integration you can get it separately [here](http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/Castle+Visual+Studio+Integration), but it's only good for NVelocity.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get started with the tutorial?  You can find it here:

[Castle ActiveRecord - Getting Started - Requirements](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/requirements.html)

It tells you which DLLs you need to add to your project.

Comment: I did, but I didn't pay it to much attention cause I was sure that VS wouldn't list the dlls. But then I found the "browse"-tab. Incidentally, how does VS know which dlls to list?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a project that provides integration for both versions - have you tried it?

http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/Castle+Visual+Studio+Integration

If that doesn't work, what additional features are you looking for that we can help with?

Comment: It's just the nvelocity integration.